# What happens when both developers work on same file and commit it, update and etc

Tags: git, github

We want to start an open source project and use Git with my friend. We know about Git, but we only used it for forking things before/work alone.

Let's say we've created a repository.

**Situation 1:**

```
Both of us downloaded repository to our local computers to started working.
I've created A.php, with a function named A() in it. Committed.
My friend created B.php, with a function named B() in it. Committed.
```

Q1: Our local repositories aren't updated but github repository is updated. How can we sync it without downloading the entire repo again?

Q2: How often do developers update their local repositories? I may update it at 20:00, but there may be a different commit at 20:05. Is there any realtime solutions for updating local repos? Like dropbox in this case, you make a change and it automatically sync it.

**Situation 2**

```
Me and my friend both started working on A.php. The file currently has function A(). 
I made a function called function B(), committed.
My friend also created a function called B() too. Committed.
```

Q3: What is going to happen? Do the first committer commits normally, and the second committer gets an error like "File changed, please sync the file again and commit afterwards."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: You use Fetch or Pull to get the latest changes from the origin repo.

Q2: Every time they must do it, either because they want to see what has happened in the origin repo, or because git forces them to do so. Indeed, if you try to push to the remote origin repo and your local copy is behind it, git will force you to update your local copy first, merge of rebase your changes, and then push again.

Q3: Yes, the second push will be rejected. The developer will have to fetch, merge or rebase, and thus solve the potential conflicts, and then push.

I recommend reading [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book), which is both excellent, and free.

Comment: Lisa are you planning on accepting any of the answers to any of your questions?

Comment: @AlienWebguy I was away for a while. I leave no questions without selecting an answer. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

A1. Why do you need this? You could do `git pull` to pull changes of repository to your local. Where is no other way to recieve data, only fetching whole changes

A2. Realy you could do it as you need. If you don't need other's functionality, you may not be updating a while. If you need it - pull it.

I always checkouting after every implemented feature, because many developers working on similar file. Less changes I've done, easier to resolve conflicts.

A3. Git does not merge functions it merges source files. If one added A() at begining of file, another at the end, everything would be merged successfully, and there would be two A()'s.

You should merge or rebase in order to push to remote, where you not HEAD

Answer (score 0):

In response to your request for guides that will answer your questions, I have a few suggestions. I am new to git, but I've been hanging out in the #git IRC on esper.net and soaking up information. Here are the tutorials/guides I've found that I thought were most helpful.

- [Ry's Git Tutorial](http://rypress.com/tutorials/git/index.html) By far my favorite. Very clear and simple tutorial that guides you gently through every aspect of git.
- [Intro to Git](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2009/03/intro-to-git-for-web-designers/) Not the smoothest tutorial, but it has a great "cheat sheet" and many useful links at the bottom.
- try.github.com This is github's starter tutorial. As you've already been using it locally this link would better help a total beginner.
- gitolite.com/master-toc.html One person's extensive and quite dense notes on using git.

Hope these links have helped! I'm sure all of your questions and more could be answered through these tutorials.